# How to follow specific journal or conference in google scholar for new paper?

Tags: google-scholar

I want to follow few journal and conference. IS it possible to create alert for such specific item in google scholar? or is there any other system available for these kind of tasks?

Answer (score 1):

Many conferences and journals have RSS feeds that you can aggregate with an [RSS reader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/News_aggregator). Usually they are linked on the conference / journal website (though sometimes you need to search for "rss" in the page source because it is hidden somewhere).

Example: the [arXiv math.AG](https://arxiv.org/list/math.AG/recent) site doesn't mention RSS anywhere, but the page source [does](http://export.arxiv.org/rss/math.AG).

Comment: There's also this page on [RSS news feeds for arXiv updates](https://arxiv.org/help/rss) from their help pages, which documents the naming scheme and some further options.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn any Google Scholar search into a search alert that will send you periodic email updates. So if you have a search for a particular journal, something like:

> source:Biogeosciences

You can enter that into the form for creating a new alert at https://scholar.google.com/scholar_alerts?view_op=create_alert_options&alert_params=hl%3Den&hl=en

For a journal or conference name with spaces you should enclose it in quotes like:

> source:"ACS National Meeting"

You may not get the results you expect if the journal name is abbreviated or truncated in some way (or if it is not released in a way that is crawled by Google Scholar), but once you find the most common way that the name shows up in Google Scholar results, you should be good to go in most cases.